# Facebook Graph API - comments from other users not showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I'm using the Facebook Graph API and previously, using the /me/posts endpoint and including the comments field, I'd get a list of posts including all comments.

Now I've tried it again, it's not bringing back any comments unless they are my own. This is through the Facebook Graph Explorer and it's behaving the same there though so it's not my application

This is the endpoint I am using

```
me/posts?fields=from,message,comments
```

If I put .summary(1) at the end, it shows me there's, for example, 3 comments on a post but the 'data' will just be a blank area.

Has there been a change on Facebook recently in regards to this?

Comment: Have you found any solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0#comments-edge

> When read with a User access token, the /comments edge returns empty data for the following nodes...

A lot has changed in the last few weeks, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So does this mean I can no longer get the comments of a post, even if a user authenticates?

Comment: you can test it, but from what i read in the changelog, i would say no.

Comment: @andyrandy Is there any way to fetch comments of a post now?

Comment: @Chris I think there is no way to get any comments from users' any Post, Album, Photo or Video nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the comments with a Page Token, not a user or App token.

Comment: Please give a more detailed answer.

Comment: This means "User access token" is unable to get comments of Album, Photo, Post, Video nodes. In other words, you can't get any comment from user's any Post, Album, Photo or Video.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get post_id from the feed and for each post with post_id get all the comments for the post. It has worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations, documentation, and examples, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.